# How is malloc handled at compile time and run time?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

Is malloc used to specify at compile time - a maximum size of a buffer(array) pointed to by a pointer and then allocated that max sized buffer by default in run-time and later - only that part of the buffer is actually used (though full size was allocated) that we need (by taking data from user etc) ?

If the above is true - then that means malloc (used along pointers) essentially provides a way to model a (including higher dimensions - but for eg -2) 2-D array as a 1-d array of pointers, and then at compile time specify the size of buffer to be allocated to each individual pointer i.e. essentially accomplishing the same thing as declaring it as a 2-D array with max dimensions specified in declaration at compile time - but just allowing to model/visualize it differently. Both are allocated the default max size - array type declaration at the the run of the declaration statement, while pointer+ malloc type at the run of the malloc statement (I do think this size information is used in both cases to calculate the size of stack+heap sum required for run).

That is in pointer+malloc, once compiler sees that this information (max buffer size for each pointer using malloc) is available at compile time - compilation can go through as it has the information of how much memory to allocate by default and can (and does) also use that information to calculate the size of stack+heap sum required for the function run (if no malloc - then it points to a single element). Later at run-time - the max sized buffer is allocated after malloc statement is run, to be later used as input needs.

Comment: Nobody can understand this abracadabra, dude.

Comment: `malloc()` is called at runtime and allocates memory at runtime; the compiler does not do any memory allocation via `malloc()` as far as the program is concerned (though the compiler's internals do lots of dynamic memory allocation).  That seems to be what the first sentence is asking about.  The rest is indigestible — but I think it's based on the false premise that `malloc()` can somehow be done at compile time and hence is not actually relevant.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler. I dont know what made me write "allocated at compile -time". I meant default max_size is specified at compile time (which is required if pointer type declaration must point to starting element of a non-singular data - else by default it points to a singular-element), so seeing this information available - compilation can proceed. All memory except global and static variables is actually allocated at run time when the actual function is executed. Edited my question to make more sense than before.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The OP needs to clarify the question, but we cannot dismiss the possibility of the compiler providing for memory allocation at compile time instead of run time. I just compiled `#include <stdio.h>` / `#include <stdlib.h>` / `int main(void) { int *a = malloc(sizeof *a); *a = 4; printf("%d\n", *a); }` to assembly with Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2) with `-O3`, and the resulting assembly does not contain any reference to `malloc`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil what you see is the rule of "observable behavior"

Comment: @bolov: Yes. And it remains true. We cannot assert that `malloc` is performed only at run time and dismiss the possibility that the compiler provides for allocation or other behavior at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason why allocating memory using `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc` is called [dynamic memory management](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory). Dynamic in this context means that which happens at run-time. This does not happen at compile time.

> If the above is true...

Since it is not true, what follows is not derivable from it.

Comment: Thanks @P.W I dont know what made me write "allocated at compile -time". I meant default max_size is specified at compile time (which is required if pointer type declaration must point to starting element of a non-singular data - else by default it points to a singular-element), so seeing this information available - compilation can proceed. All memory except global and static variables is actually allocated at run time when the actual function is executed. Edited my question to make more sense than before

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` is a function of the standard C library.

All functions are called at runtime.

The only thing that happens at compile time is creating a function call to `malloc`

Comment: Not all functions are called at run time. I just compiled `#include <stdio.h>` / `#include <stdlib.h>` / `int main(void) { int *a = malloc(sizeof *a); *a = 4; printf("%d\n", *a); }` to assembly with Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2) with `-O3`, and the resulting assembly does not contain any reference to `malloc`.

Comment: Does it use a pointer variable at all? The compiler can optimize as long as it still behaves as if the original code was compiled.